# NAudio AudioMeterInformation works only if "control mmsys.cpl sounds" is open

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I'm trying to capture the sound of MIC (DataFlow.Capture), but AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues only works if sound properties is open (control mmsys.cpl sounds)

Working example

[image: Working]

But when i close sound properties..

[image: Not working]

My code

```
    private void calculateChannels(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        dev = devEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Capture, Role.Multimedia);

        try
        {
            double currentLeftChannel = 100 - (dev.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[0] * 100);
            double currentRightChannel = 100 - (dev.AudioMeterInformation.PeakValues[1] * 100);

            // this function just "smooth" the progress bar
            this.leftChannel = round(this.leftChannel, currentLeftChannel);
            this.rightChannel = round(this.rightChannel, currentRightChannel);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

    }
```

I'm used (-100) on the result because my progress bar is inverted (black colors are actually the progress)

DataFlow.Render is working fine, even without properties open.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to put WaveInEvent on my constructor to enable the device.

```
waveInStream = new WaveInEvent();
waveInStream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
waveInStream.StartRecording();
```

Now, It is working.